# kubernetes vs Docker DNS configuration

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Using Docker on Mac, I am trying to port docker run parameters to kubernetes yaml configuration, today we are running a container with following DNS flags:

--dns="8.8.8.8" --dns="8.8.4.4"

when I do docker inspect on this container I see:

```
"Dns": [
        "8.8.8.8",
        "8.8.4.4"
       ]
```

After reading the Kubernetes docs, I configured the pod yaml like this:

```
  dnsPolicy: "None"
  dnsConfig:
    nameservers:
      - 8.8.8.8
      - 8.8.4.4
```

But when I do docker inspect on the container that Kubernetes launched I see

```
 "Dns": null
```

Is that expected? is the configuration correct? maybe Kubernetes networking bypasses the container configurations so the container is not aware... I simply don't know.

Comment: Hi perhaps the value of dnsPolicy should be different,  it you want to append the value from host then 'ClusterFirstWithHostNet' might be useful

Comment: what if you `cat /etc/resolv.conf` inside the container? What do you see?

Comment: @SureshVishnoi according to docs and the k8s code on github dnsPolicy should be None in order for dnsConfig to take effect.

Comment: @fiunchinho, it shows my mac settings (with other nameservers)

Comment: Hi, I used the above values and I got the following values 
```
sh-4.2# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
sh-4.2#
```

Comment: It seems its working fine for me

Comment: @SureshVishnoi and fiunchinho you meant that I should run this inside the container... so yes, I get same values as you, guess that docker daemon is simply not aware of these options if they are set by k8s, Thanks!

Comment: These values are given by kubelt to docker, it tells docker that please put this content to /etc/resolv.conf (inside container) rather then docker takes values from the host and put it in the container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As fiunchinho clarified the behavior is correct. Configuring [Pod DNS policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-dns-policy) will have impact on the container, but you won't be able to see that through docker commands, like in few other cases. This is because docker and Kubernetes operate on different layers of the stack.

So adding the DNS parameter to `docker run` will result in writing them in `/etc/resolv.conf` and the same thing happens with adding `dnsConfig` although in the last example Docker will not be aware of it. So answering the question, yes this is expected behavior.